# How to get all record which datetime less than datetime now using linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4

I have table with datetime filed, I want all record which datetime less than datetime now using linq to SQL

```
 var list =db.MyTable.Where(t => t.Date < DateTime.Today).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DateTime.Now` property in the condition.

Difference between `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Now`:

`DateTime.Today` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Gets the current date.

`DateTime.Now` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on
>   this computer, expressed as the local time.

Let's say that we run your query at 18:33:15 on 18 February 2015.

If you use `DateTime.Today`, the sql query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t WHERE t.Date < '2015-02-18 00:00:00'
```

And if you use `DateTime.Now`, the sql query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t WHERE t.Date < '2015-02-18 18:33:15'
```

Example:

Sample data:

```
    1   test1   2015-02-18 18:22:13.000
    2   test2   2015-02-17 18:24:56.000
    3   test3   2015-02-18 13:25:05.000
    4   test4   2015-02-20 18:29:48.000
```

If you use `.Where(t => t.Date < DateTime.Today)` the result will be:

```
2   test2   2015-02-17 18:24:56.000
```

If you use `.Where(t => t.Date < DateTime.Now)` the result will be:

```
1   test1   2015-02-18 18:22:13.000
2   test2   2015-02-17 18:24:56.000
3   test3   2015-02-18 13:25:05.000
```